# Align issue with a font when trying to stretch with dynamic letter-spacing

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, google-font-api

I'm trying to get some "one-word" lines justified, I've got a jQuery script that does it from another question on this site and I implemented it in my website. The problem is that it works, but not perfectly, it leaves some spaces at the extremes of the line. After a lot of debugging i've found that it is because of the google-font i'm using, or better: i think that this is the problem cause if I use the default font it works perfectly..

Another really strange thing is that if I resize the browser (I'm using Chrome) the problem disappears and comes back only if I refresh the page..

Now, for the code, for some reason (maybe the resize question) I can't reproduce the error in a simplier jsfiddle but I can link the website and give you any other piece of code if needed.

[Live problem](http://arter.altervista.org/xandru/)

Look at the "B" at the end of the first line, i've put up a grid to highlight the problem.

Comment: First time I visited it it was overlapping the red border... second time (without resizing, looks fine). Can you replicate?

Comment: Open up the 'live problem' and hit refresh... what do you see happen?

Comment: Everytime I refresh I see the B overlapping the red border.

Comment: And you want the letters to always sit flush with that red border right? Also... are you seeing that the word 'Applications' is always working? Just troubleshooting at this stage :-)

Comment: Yes, I want it to be perfectly aligned but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding style of margin left and right set to either zero or auto?